# How to show data in recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want get **country** data from server and show into `recyclerView`. I can show data into `recyclerView`!
For show county data from server I write below codes :

```
    public void getCountryData() {
        countryDialog = new Dialog(context);
        countryDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        countryDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_country);
        countryRecycler = (RecyclerView) countryDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryRecyclerView);
        countryProgress = (ProgressBar) countryDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryDialog_progress);
        countryRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        countryRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        countryProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        countryProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8d00"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<CountryResponse> call = api.getCountryList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    models.clear();
                    models.addAll(response.body().getData());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CountryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.failRequest),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            }
        });
        countryDialog.show();
    }
```

I use `Retrofit2` for requests.

I write above code into `onClickListiner` event in `EditText`.
I should first get country from **IP** and for this way I use another request, and for this I write below codes:

```
public void getCountryFromIP() {
    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getIPClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CountryFromIP> call = api.getCountryFromIP();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryFromIP>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryFromIP> call, Response<CountryFromIP> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                countryEdt.setText(response.body().getCountryName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CountryFromIP> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

I use **getCountryFromIP()** in `onCreate` , when use `getCountryFromIP()` code in my application show country from IP and set into `editText` but when click on this `editText` (when click on show list of country dialog) not show any country data into `recyclerView` and not gone `progressBar`!

But when delete `getCountryFromIP()` from onCreate() show country data into `recyclerView` and gone `progressBar`!

How can I fix this strange error? please help me.

Comment: You only need `countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter)` in `onCreate`, not during the `onResponse`... But are you getting data at all? How much did you debug?

Comment: I don't understand this question... `getCountryFromIP()` never edits a RecyclerView

Comment: @cricket_007, yes I get all dada. can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: @cricket_007, yes my issue is very strange! when use `getCountryFromIP()` n onCreate not show data into dialog, but when delete `getCountryFromIP()` show data into dialog! why?!!!

Comment: Send you what code? I don't understand the problem completely without a [mcve]. Also, add some `Log` statements to your code so you see when the requests complete vs. error.

Answer (score 0):

You are notifying adapter but where u have passer arraylist in adapter u have to initialize adapter before using recyclerview.setAdapter();

Please check onResponse() code

```
public void getCountryData() {
        countryDialog = new Dialog(context);
        countryDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        countryDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_country);
        countryRecycler = (RecyclerView) countryDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryRecyclerView);
        countryProgress = (ProgressBar) countryDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryDialog_progress);
        countryRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        countryRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        countryProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        countryProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8d00"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<CountryResponse> call = api.getCountryList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    models.clear();
                    models.addAll(response.body().getData());
 madapter=new MyAdapter(context,models);
// I don't know which parameter u have passed in adapter i m just showing u the way how to implement

 countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CountryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.failRequest),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            }
        });
        countryDialog.show();
    }
```

Hope this will help u...if any questions u can ask

Answer (score 0):

Your should change **ApiClient** class with other requests!

```
public void getCountryFromIP() {
    InterfaceApi api = ApiClientIP.getIPClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CountryFromIP> call = api.getCountryFromIP();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryFromIP>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryFromIP> call, Response<CountryFromIP> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                countryEdt.setText(response.body().getCountryName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CountryFromIP> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

replace this code with your codes and write **ApiClient** codes from **getIP** into **ApiClientIP** and fix your bug.

Hope help you man.